# How to access Firebug's information from Firebug's console?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is the info that Firebug shows under various tabs available also within the console?

E.g. within the command line I can create objects, do simple math, execute JavaScript etc. For example I can create an object for an HTTP request:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But I am wondering if there is some 'global' variable, which actually holds the `request` variable and which I can read from. Something like:

```
console.log(global_http_request.referring_url);
```

Please note, I am not aware of how to show the referring URL from which I've come to the current page (for this I can use e.g. Firefox' *Tools* > *Page info* and search for "Referring URL" or Firebug's *Net* panel and filter by *XHR*).

I've tried this (within the console) to access the referring URL, but with no luck:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
undefined
console.log(request.HEADERS_RECEIVED)
2
console.log(request.HEADERS_RECEIVED.valueOf)
valueOf()
console.log(request.HEADERS_RECEIVED.toString)
toString()
console.log(request.HEADERS_RECEIVED.toString())
2
console.log(request.HEADERS_RECEIVED.valueOf())
2
console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders.name.valueOf.toString())

function valueOf() {
    [native code]
}

console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders())
(an empty string)
```

Comment: Isn't the variable `request` what you want??

Comment: The title of your question is quite confusing. Your question seems to be rather related to how to get the referrer of an XHR than about Firebug.

Comment: So I assume your question is actually how to get the `Referer` request header of an XHR from within JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of data you cannot get using standard JS, but which Firebug has access to because it runs with higher privileges than the web page. I think response headers are run through a black list, for instance.

However, if you just want JS access to the data for simplified debugging, you should be able to get that in Firebug by right-clicking the XHR object and picking "Use in Command Line".

Comment: This is interesting because some pages does shows nothing under: "XHR" and another which I have open right now says that referrer is the same page (obtained by steps you've mentioned via $p) and page info in Firefox says that referrer is stackoverflow page.

Comment: So the short answer is: no it is not possible? What about `window` object that was mentioned in another answer?

Comment: FWIW, I just tested things, and it appears that to get the Firebug info from the XHR you need to right-click the XHR request from the Net panel - the console panel gives you a plain XHR object. But that should give you back exactly what you see in Firebug. Anyway, I'm actually rather confused as to exactly what you're asking (e.g. what's an "actual XHR" except the one you created?), but I don't think you'll find a way other than the ones given.

Comment: I'm asking if `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();` does not create completely new (and probably empty) instance of `XMLHttpRequest()` which has nothing to do with the `XMLHttpRequest()` that was used during loading my page? If yes then @ epascarello answer wont work. I was also not successful with `window` object.

Comment: Yes, that creates a completely new empty instance.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am wondering if there is some 'global' variable which actually
>   holds my actual XMLHttpRequest() and which I can read from ?

This global object is called `window`.

Comment: Pardon my stupid question but I've tried to get mentioned refferers via `console.log(window.XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED.toString)` and it returns me nothing. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have named your variable `request`, so you might try looking for `window.request` or just `request`. Of course the received you can read the response headers only after the asynchronous request has completed executing.

Comment: Doesn't `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();` created new `XMLHttpRequest()` object? I mean new it has nothing to do with the original that already exists somewhere and has set values.